# Validación en Laravel por múltiples columnas

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-9, laravel-10

Buenas tardes compañeros,
Me encuentro realizando una app y necesito poder validar campos, La idea es permitir duplicar pCode , pero sólo cuando la combinación pCode + company no exista en base de datos, actualmente tengo una regla personalizada de esta forma.

```
public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail)
{
    $product = DB::table('product')
        ->where('pCode', '=', $value)
        ->where('company', '=', Auth::user()->company)
        ->first();

    if ($product) $fail('El codigo ya se encuentra registrado en la base de datos');

}
```

y lo agrego en mi formResquest de la siguiente forma.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'pCode' => ['required' , 'string' , new UniqueProduct()],
            'pBarCode' => 'nullable|string',
            'pReference' => 'nullable|string',
            'pName' => 'required|string'
        ];
    }
```

esto me funciona, lo que quiero es que al actualizar el producto no me tenga en cuenta en la validación el campo pCode cuando no lo he modificado pero si lo modifico que si haga la validación, ya que al momento de actualizar por ejemplo el campo pName como también van los dotos del pCode pues me frena en la validación, de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.